# Angular how to use ngModel correctly? Why I get undefined and errors?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngmodel

I'm having some issues with this code, Angular logs "undefined" when I use the input field, its a basic component, but can't make it work.

HTML template:

```
<h1>{{ titulo }}</h1>
<ul>
  <li>hlelo</li>
  <li>hlelo</li>
  <li>hlelo</li>
  <li>hlelo</li>
  <li>hlelo</li>
</ul>

Nombre del parque:

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nombreDelParque" (keyup)="mostrarNombre()" />

// this is not binding --> 

Resultado {{ nombreDelParque }}

<br />

<parques></parques>
```

TS file:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'tienda',
  templateUrl: './tienda.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tienda.component.css'],
})
export class TiendaComponent {
  public titulo: string;
  public nombreDelParque: string;
 
  constructor() {
    this.titulo = 'esta es la tienda';
  }
 
  mostrarNombre() {
    console.log(this.nombreDelParque);
  }
}
```

Error message in chrome's browser console and when using the input field I get logged undefined on the console.

```
Error: src/app/components/tienda/tienda.component.html:18:20 - error NG8002:  
 Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
        
18 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nombreDelParque" (keyup)="mostrarNombre()" />
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        
src/app/components/tienda/tienda.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './tienda.component.html',
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component TiendaComponent.
```

Comment: Import `FormsModule` in `app.module.ts` file

Comment: Works fine for me. Make sure you have imported FormsModule as per the above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import `FormsModule` in `app.module.ts` to use `ngModal`. Also if you are using `formbuilder` you'll need `ReactiveFormsModule` for that. Don't forget to add these modules to import list.
Here is how your `app.module.ts` should look:

```js
// your modules
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // your modules
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ], 
  declarations: []
  }
)
```

Comment: it was that. thanks!